# iPhone GO click is considering the enabled button instead of disabled when there are two submit buttons in the form

Tags: html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on a web application which has multiple screens, every screen has 2 submit buttons(1 is the Back button and the other is next button) like below.

```
<input name="submit" class="order-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" disabled>
<input name="back" class="order-1 btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" type="submit" value="Back" 
formnovalidate formaction="BackToIndex?tabId=@Model.TabId">
```

The "Next" button is enabled only when all the required fields are filled up in the form, so when I click on GO button when the Next button is disabled it is redirecting me to previous page(which means Back button action is hitting)...
But it should not do that instead it should be in the same page when the "Next" is disabled.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid go button go back to the previous page? In my opinion, this is by design. The browser's go button is used to go back to the previous page. It will save the previous page url, if the user click the go button, it will redirect to the previous page url. We couldn't modify this behavior.

Comment: I am not talking about the browser Go back I am talking my my Back button in the form

Comment: I'm still confused about your requirement. Do you mean you want to prevent redirect to `BackToIndex` when the Next button is disabled?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Yes... You are correct